# NSInvalidArgumentException not being caught in code

Tags: objective-c, ios, exception, try-catch, nsexception

I'm using selectors to dynamically call functions in Objective-C. My problem is that my `@try`/`@catch` block is not catching the exception if I pass an non-existent function name.

In the console I get an uncaught `NSInvalidArgumentException` and further down I get an uncaught `NSException`.

I have tried catching the the two types of exceptions in a standard `@try`/`@catch` block but they aren't registering. Xcode won't let me compile if I try to catch `NSInvalidArgumentException` as it's not a recognized type.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

```
@try {
    SEL s = NSSelectorFromString(@"funName");
    [self performSelector:s withObject: nil];
} 
@catch (NSException/NSInvalidArgumentException exception) {
     NSLog(@"ERROR: %@", [exception message/reason];
}
```

Comment: Sure, no problem. Sorry I didn't the first add code the first time around.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Many consider this to be a bug.

See http://openradar.appspot.com/8081169

By testing similar code, I can make it work on a device but not in the simulator.

Comment: Ugh, that doesn't seem to work at all for me :(

Have you tried to above code?

Thanks for the input though.

Comment: @Conor H - That was an answer to you question - it's a bug in the Simulator, and you're recommended to file a bug. Have you tried this cod on the device?

Comment: Thanks guys,
I can't try this yet as the iPad is out of the office but i'll mark this as answered.

Thanks!